# Php explode then get the name row from a MySql Table

Tags: php, loops, foreach, explode

I know this has been talked about here before. However, my situation is a bit different and I'm so close.

I would like to explode an array of category id's from a news data table then get the category name from the category table.

Right now I am able to get the id's out and explode them just fine inside the while loop for the news data using:

```
    $post_cats_data = $news_data['cat_id']; // 1,6,7,11
    $post_cats_id = explode(",", $post_cats_data);
```

Now where I'm getting stuck is getting the news categories and echoing out the name.

```
 $cat_count = count($post_cats_id);
 $i = 0;
     foreach($post_cats_id as $cat_id){
       $cat_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news_categories WHERE `cat_id` = '$cat_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $cat_title_row = mysql_fetch_row($cat_qry) or die(mysql_error());
      $i++;
      $write_cat .= $cat_title_row['cat_name'] ;
        if($i<$cat_count){
           $write_cat .= ', ';
        }

 }
```

The idea is that this will get the category names from the category tables that were exploded and will add a comma back to the end of everyone but the last one. I am unable to get the category name and when I return the ID it loops though the id for all the news.

I know this is a simple problem, I'm just new to using loops.

Comment: Also, you can compress your SQL into a single statement using `IN` like this: `$s= "SELECT * FROM news_categories WHERE cat_id IN ($post_cats_data)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row` returns an array indexed at 0, so `$cat_title_row['cat_name']` will not give you the desired results.  Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead and it should work fine.

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php):

> mysql_fetch_row() returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the
>   fetched row, or FALSE if there are no
>   more rows.
>
> mysql_fetch_row() fetches one row of
>   data from the result associated with
>   the specified result identifier. The
>   row is returned as an array. Each
>   result column is stored in an array
>   offset, starting at offset 0.

Comment: That worked, now I feel silly. I also hate that I was sooo close!

Answer (score 0):

you could just use `mysql_result` like this:

```
$cat_title = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM news_categories WHERE `cat_id` = '$cat_id'"),0);
```

if you want them all in a comma delimited list you could use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) like this:

```
$cat_titles = array();
foreach($post_cats_id as $cat_id){
  $cat_title = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM news_categories WHERE `cat_id` = '$cat_id'"),0);
  $cat_titles[] = $cat_title;
}
$comma_cat_titles = implode(',',$cat_titles);
```

To get it all done in a single query you could do something like:

```
$cat_titles = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`cat_name` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `news_categories` WHERE `cat_id` IN (".$post_cats_data.")"),0);
```

Comment: What is the "0" for at the end of the query is that for error reporting?

Comment: the 0 is the row number from the result set that's being retrieved